# How to take location data from Google Maps and store it in a database?

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, database, google-maps

I am building a website which have users, and users have profiles where they can edit their information. One of user's information elements is to enter their location based on a google map API that is going to be appeared in front of them.

My question is: how can i take the location the user picked on the map and store it in the database? ("assuming that i already built the database and i got the longitude and latitude as inputs within user table ")

i have added a picture which is a simple front-end illustration i have made to explain what i am trying to do.

[front end example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zyHj.jpg)

Comment: Something like [this](https://www.latlong.net/) ? Check their source, starting at line 207, it is simple...add event listener,then on click store into variable and insert into html input value.

Comment: Can you put your code also? So that we can provide a more specific answer to your question.

Comment: Are you still working on this or it is solved?

Comment: I think this question is trying to ask how their database schema should be modeled

Answer (score -1):

A simple example where you can store users' inputs into a database can be found here, in the [Google Documentation itself](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/info-windows-to-db).

In essence, you use an infoWindow with HTML input elements to get users' inputs. You can then use this function to save data, as an example:

```
function saveData() {
    var name = escape(document.getElementById('name').value);
    var address = escape(document.getElementById('address').value);
    var latlng = marker.getPosition();
    var url = 'phpsqlinfo_addrow.php?name=' + name + '&address=' + address + '&lat=' + latlng.lat() + '&lng=' + latlng.lng();

    downloadUrl(url, function(data, responseCode) {

      if (responseCode == 200 && data.length <= 1) {
        infowindow.close();
        messagewindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    });
  }
```

In the documentation the example is set in JS, PHP and MySQL; you can also use something more lightweight such as `SQlite` to store data locally and do your CRUD operations using `Python DB-API`.